# Best way to go about converting Outlook mails and attachments to PDF (preferably merging them)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf, outlook-addin

I'm creating an Outlook add-in that needs to archive Outlook emails programmatically as PDF, including the mail attachments. At the moment, it saves the Outlook message as PDF but the attachment as the filetype it was sent as (doc, png, excl etc).

Whats the correct approach to doing this? I can't seem to figure out how, without having to create files an delete them repeatedly. The process that I'm thinking I have to do is: Save mail as PDF, save attachment, convert saved attachment from normal filetype to PDF, delete old file, create new PDF file merging both mail and attachment, delete old files. It just seems so silly and unnecessary, but I don't really know what other approach I'd use?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the attachments. The [Attachment.SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method saves the attachment to the specified path. The location at which to save the attachment should be passed as a parameter. For example:

```
Sub SaveAttachment() 
 Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector  
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem  
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 
 
 Set myInspector = Application.ActiveInspector  
 If Not TypeName(myInspector) = "Nothing" Then  
   If TypeName(myInspector.CurrentItem) = "MailItem" Then  
     Set myItem = myInspector.CurrentItem  
     Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments  
     'Prompt the user for confirmation  
     Dim strPrompt As String  
     strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the first attachment in the current item to the Documents folder? If a file with the same name already exists in the destination folder, it will be overwritten with this copy of the file."  
     If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then  
        myAttachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\My Documents\" & myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName  
     End If  
   Else  
     MsgBox "The item is of the wrong type."  
   End If  
 End If  
End Sub
```

To save an Outlook item you need to use the [MailItem.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.saveas?view=outlook-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Outlook__MailItem_SaveAs_System_String_System_Object_) method which saves the Microsoft Outlook item to the specified path and in the format of the specified file type. If the file type is not specified, the MSG format (.msg) is used.

After that you can do the required conversations to PDF and etc.